# hide a div that has been shown up by onkeyup event (hide when click outside of it)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML code is following:

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <form>
     <input id="search" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" type="text" />
    </form>
    <div style="position:relative;">
       <div id="suggestions" style="position:absolute;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is following:

```
$("#search").blur(function(){
   $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
});
```

My JavaScript code is following:

```
function lookup(inputString)
{
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $.post("/ajax/search/", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { 
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
            $('#suggestions').html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

I tried following but it did not work:

```
$(document.body).click(function(){
   if (!$('#suggestions').has(this).length) {
    $('#suggestions').hide();
    }
});
```

My question is how to hide a `#suggestions` when I click outside the `#suggestions` div. Now it only gets away when there are no characters in #search

Answer (score 1):

Don't do any checks inside the document click:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('#suggestions').hide();
});
```

If you additionally want to leave the item visible if the div `suggestions` is clicked, add this:

```
$('#suggestions').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX5PT/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('html').click(function(e){
   if (!($(e.target).is('#suggestions'))&&($(e.target).closest('#suggestions').length==0)) {
    $('#suggestions').hide();
    }
});
```